# postgresql views + regexp -> optimizer issue?

Tags: postgresql

I have view selecting data from couple of tables and noticed performance issues when started using regexp

Executing simple query can takes ~30 seconds (returns only 200 rows...)

```
SELECT *  
FROM  api.view1
JOIN ....
WHERE ....
      AND num ~ '^124456[67]$';
```

I noticed problematic part is "num ~ '^124456[67]$';"

Rewriting that to below **shorten time to few ms** only !

```
with x as (
SELECT *  
    FROM  api.view1
    JOIN ....
    WHERE ....
)
select * from x WHERE num ~ '^124456[67]$';
```

If I resign from view and I'll use same query & regex - all work well.

So it looks to me as **optimizer issue** (unless Im not doing something wrong here)

Can someone advice how to tell optimizer to go right way?

**** EDIT ****

Please note given regex was just an example, I know I can resign form regex in above example but I have also more complex expressions.

Comment: A good answer can only be given if we know the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the slow query.

Comment: As of Postgres 11 a CTE (`with...`)  is optimized independently from the rest of the query - and this is an example where this approach obviously makes sense. Note that this behaviour will change in Postgres 12 (but you can influence it)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Postgres actually materializes all common table expressions.  So, the improvement in performance likely has to do with that all the filtering of the original query's `WHERE` clause already happened before you applied the regex filter.

Here is one way you could rewrite the query, which might perform a bit better than the full regex version:

```
SELECT *  
FROM api.view1
JOIN ....
WHERE ....
    AND num IN (1244566, 1244567);
```

Note that you don't really need to even use a regex here.  Instead, try just comparing `num` against the two literal values which you expect.  The other advantage of the above approach is that it potentially leaves the door open for an index to be used, which could make the query even faster.  Your current regex approach would probably rule out an index, at least for the `num` column.

Comment: Given regex was just an example, I know I can replace it by IN (...) or AND (num=x OR num=y) in this case but I have also more complex expressions. 
Nevertheless my question was why regex usage kills performance here and if there is a way to give some tips optimizer to do not perform full table scan on all rows of oryginal table, but just on result limited previously by WHERE clause (soin my case ~200 rows)

Comment: Regex is generally a very costly thing to do in SQL (or any other language).  It basically eliminates the chance of using any index, so peformance is not good.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Postgres can use a [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) to speed up a regex condition

Comment: Guys - I know any pattern marching (like regex similar to etc) is obviously costly. But we are talking here about 200 records to filter out... Issue is postgres runs regex on all table rows instead those filtered out by where cause. Also this doesn't happen when I resign from view and use directly oryginal view query  I don't have similar experience from other DB engines